# ASP.NET MVC - Printing is not taking full page width

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, printing

I'm trying to print my internet pages and I used that code sample to make it fit to an A4 format :

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, my page is not entirely displayed (for instance, I'm showing a scheduler and I don't get the entire component on the print preview).

Any idea of what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing a bit more about what you're doing, but perhaps the scheduler component is too large for the page? You need to make sure that whatever you are printing fits on the allotted space by comparing the number of pixels. You may be able to scale whatever goes on the page using CSS, although some objects do not scale. Is there text on the page as well, or just the scheduler component?